# SQL SERVER generate data using Regex pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, masking, sql-masking

I would like to generate the data by given regex pattern in `SQL Server`. Is there any possibility to do? Say, I have pattern as below and I would like to generate data as follow:

The idea behind the concept is **[SQL STATIC DATA MASKING](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5939/sql-server-static-data-masking-example/)** (which was removed in [current feature](https://merlecarr.wordpress.com/2019/04/27/what-happened-to-sql-server-static-data-masking/)). Our client wants to mask the production data in test database. We don't have SQL STATIC DATA MASKING feature with sql now but we have patterns to mask the column, so what I am thinking is, with these pattern we can run the update query.

```
SELECT "(\d){7}" AS RandonNumber, "(\W){5}" AS RandomString FROM tbl
```

**Output Should be**

```
  +---------------+--------------+
  |  RandonNumber | RandomString |
  +---------------+--------------+
  |  7894562      | AHJIL        |
  +---------------+--------------+
  |  9632587      | ZLOKP        |
  +---------------+--------------+
  |  4561238      | UJIOK        |
  +---------------+--------------+
```

Apart from this regular pattern, I have some customized pattern like `Test_Product_(\d){1,4}`, which should give result as below:

```
Test_Product_012 
Test_Product_143
Test_Product_8936
```

Complete Patterns which I am going to use for masking

```
Other Patterns                Samples
(\l){30}                      ahukoklijfahukokponmahukoahuko
(\d){7}                       7895623
(\W){5}                       ABCDEF
Test_Product_(\d){1,4}        Test_Product_007
0\.(\d){2}                    0.59
https://www\.(\l){10}\.com    https://www.anything.com
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support REGEX. If you need to use REGEX you need to use CLR function. Are you not just generating an random 7 digit in and 5 character (upper case) string here though?

Comment: @Larnu Yes but I have few more patter apart from this. For example if I have pattern `Test_Product_(\d){1,4}` Then it should give `Test_Product_012, Test_Product_143,Test_Product_8936`

Comment: Then, personally, if you're going to be doing such things, I would look at a CLR route .Tthis is not my forté and I know little of REGEX, so I cannot offer a solution, however, I am sure that you can find C# scripts out there that generated strings based off of REGEX, and there are plenty of resources (including the documentation) on how to add a CLR function to SQL Server.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for your responses. Can you share the links to refer?

Comment: You won't find a built-in solution, but out of curiosity, how diverse are your masks? You've shown three options so far: A fixed length numeric and a fixed length alphanumeric masks, and then a variable length alphanumeric mask with a specific prefix. Is there anything else? I think this would probably be solvable in T-SQL if the masks are that simple and there's not too many options for them.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have few more patterns which I have updated in my edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can give you a solution that is not based on regular expressions, but on a set of parameters - but it contains a complete set of all your requirements.
I've based this solution on a user-defined function I've written to generate random strings ([You can read my blog post about it here](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/15/pre-populate-a-random-strings-pool/)) - I've just changed it so that it could generate the mask you wanted based on the following conditions:

- The mask has an optional prefix.
- The mask has an optional suffix.
- The mask has a variable-length random string.
- The random string can contain either lower-case letters, upper-case letters, digits, or any combination of the above.

I've decided these set of rules based on your update to the question, containing your desired masks:

> ```
> (\d){7}                       7895623
> (\W){5}                       ABCDEF
> Test_Product_(\d){1,4}        Test_Product_007
> 0\.(\d){2}                    0.59
> https://www\.(\l){10}\.com    https://www.anything.com
> ```

And now, for the code:
Since I'm using a user-defined function, I can't use inside it the `NewId()` built in function - so we first need to create a view to generate the guid for us:

```
CREATE VIEW GuidGenerator
AS
    SELECT Newid() As NewGuid;
```

In the function, we're going to use that view to generate a `NewID()` as the base of all randomness.

The function itself is a lot more cumbersome then the random string generator I've started from:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MaskGenerator
(
    -- use null or an empty string for no prefix
    @Prefix nvarchar(4000), 
    -- use null or an empty string for no suffix
    @suffix nvarchar(4000), 
    -- the minimum length of the random part
    @MinLength int, 
    -- the maximum length of the random part
    @MaxLength int, 
    -- the maximum number of rows to return. Note: up to 1,000,000 rows
    @Count int, 
    -- 1, 2 and 4 stands for lower-case, upper-case and digits. 
    -- a bitwise combination of these values can be used to generate all possible combinations:
    -- 3: lower and upper, 5: lower and digis, 6: upper and digits, 7: lower, upper nad digits
    @CharType tinyint 
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN 
-- An inline tally table with 1,000,000 rows
WITH E1(N) AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)) V(N)),   -- 10
     E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --100
     E3(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10,000
     Tally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID) FROM E3 a, E2 b) --1,000,000

SELECT TOP(@Count) 
        n As Number, 
        CONCAT(@Prefix, (
        SELECT  TOP (Length) 
                -- choose what char combination to use for the random part
                CASE @CharType 
                    WHEN 1 THEN Lower
                    WHEN 2 THEN Upper
                    WHEN 3 THEN IIF(Rnd % 2 = 0, Lower, Upper)
                    WHEN 4 THEN Digit
                    WHEN 5 THEN IIF(Rnd % 2 = 0, Lower, Digit)
                    WHEN 6 THEN IIF(Rnd % 2 = 0, Upper, Digit)
                    WHEN 7 THEN 
                        CASE Rnd % 3
                            WHEN 0 THEN Lower
                            WHEN 1 THEN Upper
                            ELSE Digit
                        END
                END
        FROM Tally As t0  
        -- create a random number from the guid using the GuidGenerator view
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT Abs(Checksum(NewGuid)) As Rnd FROM GuidGenerator) As rand
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            -- generate a random lower-case char, upper-case char and digit
            SELECT  CHAR(97 + Rnd % 26) As Lower, -- Random lower case letter
                    CHAR(65 + Rnd % 26) As Upper,-- Random upper case letter
                    CHAR(48 + Rnd % 10) As Digit -- Random digit
        ) As Chars
        WHERE  t0.n <> -t1.n -- Needed for the subquery to get re-evaluated for each row
        FOR XML PATH('') 
        ), @Suffix) As RandomString
FROM Tally As t1
CROSS APPLY
(
    -- Select a random length between @MinLength and @MaxLength (inclusive)
    SELECT TOP 1 n As Length
    FROM Tally As t2
    CROSS JOIN GuidGenerator 
    WHERE t2.n >= @MinLength
    AND t2.n <= @MaxLength
    AND t2.n <> t1.n
    ORDER BY NewGuid
) As Lengths;
```

### And finally, Test cases:

> `(\l){30} - ahukoklijfahukokponmahukoahuko`

```
SELECT RandomString FROM dbo.MaskGenerator(null, null, 30, 30, 2, 1);
```

Results:

```
1, eyrutkzdugogyhxutcmcmplvzofser
2, juuyvtzsvmmcdkngnzipvsepviepsp
```

> `(\d){7} - 7895623`

```
SELECT RandomString FROM dbo.MaskGenerator(null, null, 7, 7, 2, 4);
```

Results:

```
1, 8744412
2, 2275313
```

> `(\W){5} - ABCDE`

```
SELECT RandomString FROM dbo.MaskGenerator(null, null, 5, 5, 2, 2);
```

Results:

```
1, RSYJE
2, MMFAA
```

> `Test_Product_(\d){1,4} - Test_Product_007`

```
SELECT RandomString FROM dbo.MaskGenerator('Test_Product_', null, 1, 4, 2, 4);
```

Results:

```
1, Test_Product_933
2, Test_Product_7
```

> `0\.(\d){2} - 0.59`

```
SELECT RandomString FROM dbo.MaskGenerator('0.', null, 2, 2, 2, 4);
```

Results:

```
1, 0.68
2, 0.70
```

> `https://www\.(\l){10}\.com - https://www.anything.com`

```
SELECT RandomString FROM dbo.MaskGenerator('https://www.', '.com', 10, 10, 2, 1);
```

Results:

```
1, https://www.xayvkmkuci.com
2, https://www.asbfcvomax.com
```

Here's how you use it to mask the content of a table:

```
DECLARE @Count int = 10; 

SELECT  CAST(IntVal.RandomString As Int) As IntColumn, 
        UpVal.RandomString as UpperCaseValue, 
        LowVal.RandomString as LowerCaseValue, 
        MixVal.RandomString as MixedValue,
        WithPrefix.RandomString As PrefixedValue
FROM dbo.MaskGenerator(null, null, 3, 7, @Count, 4) As IntVal
JOIN dbo.MaskGenerator(null, null, 10, 10, @Count, 1) As LowVal
    ON IntVal.Number = LowVal.Number
JOIN dbo.MaskGenerator(null, null, 5, 10, @Count, 2) As UpVal
    ON IntVal.Number = UpVal.Number
JOIN dbo.MaskGenerator(null, null, 10, 20, @Count, 7) As MixVal
    ON IntVal.Number = MixVal.Number
JOIN dbo.MaskGenerator('Test ', null, 1, 4, @Count, 4) As WithPrefix
    ON IntVal.Number = WithPrefix.Number
```

Results:

```
IntColumn   UpperCaseValue  LowerCaseValue  MixedValue              PrefixedValue
674         CCNVSDI         esjyyesesv      O2FAC7bfwg2Be5a91Q0     Test 4935
30732       UJKSL           jktisddbnq      7o8B91Sg1qrIZSvG3AcL    Test 0
4669472     HDLJNBWPJ       qgtfkjdyku      xUoLAZ4pAnpn            Test 8
26347       DNAKERR         vlehbnampb      NBv08yJdKb75ybhaFqED    Test 91
6084965     LJPMZMEU        ccigzyfwnf      MPxQ2t8jjmv0IT45yVcR    Test 4
6619851     FEHKGHTUW       wswuefehsp      40n7Ttg7H5YtVPF         Test 848
781         LRWKVDUV        bywoxqizju      UxIp2O4Jb82Ts           Test 6268
52237       XXNPBL          beqxrgstdo      Uf9j7tCB4W2             Test 43
876150      ZDRABW          fvvinypvqa      uo8zfRx07s6d0EP         Test 7
```

Note that this is a fast process - generating 1000 rows with 5 columns took less than half a second on average in tests I've made.

Comment: It seems very good :) and I have one question, Is there any possibility to written function like this `SELECT dbo.MaskGenerator('https://www.', '.com', 10, 10, 2, 1);`

Comment: What I've written is an inline table-valued function. It can be converted to a scalar-valued function, but that would degrade the performance considerably. I would suggest using it as the table you want to mask and a join. I've edited my answer to include a demo at the end.

Comment: Thanks, You've inspired me to write a [new blog post](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/10/a-more-controllable-random-string-generator-function-for-sql-server/)...

Comment: I am facing one issue now. I am trying to write script using above function to mask the name column by framing query `UPDATE dbo.Projects SET Name = (SELECT TOP 1 RandomString FROM dbo.MaskGenerator('Test_Project_',null,1,4,1,4)) WHERE Name IS NOT NULL;` but its update the same value for all the rows instead of unique vales.

Comment: Because you're using `select top 1`, and you only generate a single string. You should use `cross apply` and generate as many strings as the number of records in the table. See this [online demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/ADMU91917)

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. I am facing one new issue. if I am running query with 100 count `SELECT TOP 1 RandomString FROM dbo.MaskGenerator('Test_Project_',null,1,4,100,4))` it gives me `30%` duplicates. Can we take distict values from SQL `function` ?

Comment: I made question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284859/sql-server-generate-unique-random-string

Comment: I have one more pattern `(\d){1-5}.(\d){2}` and which should give `123.76`, `45.69`, `9563.50`. Can you please help me with this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced you need a Regex for this. Why not just use a "scrub script" and take advantage of the `newid()` function to generate a bunch of random data. It looks like you'll need to write such a script anyway, Regex or not, and this has the benefit of being very simple.

Let's say you start with the following data:

```
create table tbl (PersonalId int, Name varchar(max))

insert into tbl select 300300, 'Michael'
insert into tbl select 554455, 'Tim'
insert into tbl select 228899, 'John'

select * from tbl
```

[image]

Then run your script:

```
update tbl set PersonalId = cast(rand(checksum(newid())) * 1000000 as int)
update tbl set Name = left(convert(varchar(255), newid()), 6)

select * from tbl
```

[image]

Comment: OK, yes, I am setting name to a string containing some numeric as well as alphabetic characters, but you get the point. You could write a simple SQL function to return a random alphabetic string of N characters length, etc.

Comment: I heard about `NEWID()` but I do want only string not alphanumeric. +1 for your effort.