# SQL Server Generate UNIQUE random string

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique, distinct

With help of [Zohar Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59264343/12341821), I got SQL function to generate random string but I am facing the problem with duplicate.

**Query**

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[MaskGenerator]
(    
    @Prefix nvarchar(4000), -- use null or an empty string for no prefix    
    @suffix nvarchar(4000), -- use null or an empty string for no suffix    
    @MinLength int, -- the minimum length of the random part    
    @MaxLength int, -- the maximum length of the random part    
    @Count int, -- the maximum number of rows to return. Note: up to 1,000,000 rows           
    @CharType tinyint -- 1, 2 and 4 stands for lower-case, upper-case and digits. 
                      -- a bitwise combination of these values can be used to generate all possible combinations: 
                      -- 3: lower and upper, 5: lower and digis, 6: upper and digits, 7: lower, upper nad digits
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN 

-- An inline tally table with 1,000,000 rows
WITH E1(N) AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)) V(N)), -- 10
     E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --100
     E3(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10,000
     Tally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID) FROM E3 a, E2 b) --1,000,000 

SELECT TOP(@Count)  N As Number, 
        CONCAT(@Prefix, (
        SELECT  TOP (Length) 
                -- choose what char combination to use for the random part
                CASE @CharType 
                    WHEN 1 THEN LOWER
                    WHEN 2 THEN UPPER
                    WHEN 3 THEN IIF(Rnd % 2 = 0, LOWER, UPPER)
                    WHEN 4 THEN Digit
                    WHEN 5 THEN IIF(Rnd % 2 = 0, LOWER, Digit)
                    WHEN 6 THEN IIF(Rnd % 2 = 0, UPPER, Digit)
                    WHEN 7 THEN 
                        CASE Rnd % 3
                            WHEN 0 THEN LOWER
                            WHEN 1 THEN UPPER
                            ELSE Digit
                        END
                END
        FROM Tally As T0  
        -- create a random number from the guid using the GuidGenerator view
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewGuid)) As Rnd FROM GuidGenerator) AS RAND
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            -- generate a random lower-case char, upper-case char and digit
            SELECT  CHAR(97 + Rnd % 26) As LOWER, -- Random lower case letter
                    CHAR(65 + Rnd % 26) As UPPER,-- Random upper case letter
                    CHAR(48 + Rnd % 10) As Digit -- Random digit
        ) AS Chars
        WHERE  T0.N <> -T1.N -- Needed for the subquery to get re-evaluated for each row
        FOR XML PATH('') 
        ), @Suffix) As RandomString
FROM Tally As T1 
CROSS APPLY
(
    -- Select a random length between @MinLength and @MaxLength (inclusive)
    SELECT TOP 1 N As Length
    FROM Tally As T2
    CROSS JOIN GuidGenerator 
    WHERE T2.N >= @MinLength
    AND T2.N <= @MaxLength
    AND T2.N <> t1.N
    ORDER BY NewGuid
) As Lengths;
```

Above function will provide the random string based on its parameter. For example below query will generate 100 random strings with formation of Test_Product_. the result sets having duplicate values which needs to be ignore. I have tried applying row_number but its slow down the query performance also requesting count is not coming.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MaskGenerator('Test_Product_',null,1,4,100,4) ORDER BY 2
```

I have made fiddle demo here : **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/43892/1)** and my attempt also **[here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cd842/1)**

Comment: Why not just use `newid()`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff because the OP wants to control the format of the strings generated - length, allowed chars, prefix and suffix.

Comment: If you use newid() in such a function you get an error about the use of a side-effecting operator. I guess MS expects such functions to be deterministic.  The view with the newid is basically a hack to get around that.

Comment: @LukStorms I don't think it's about determinism of the function, but rather about the side effects of the `NewId()` function - but yes - the view is simply a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this is an effect of the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).
The best solution I can offer as of now is to generate twice as many random strings you need, then select top 100 distinct values from them:

```
SELECT TOP 100 RandomString, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) As Number
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT RandomString 
  FROM dbo.MaskGenerator('Test_Product_',null,1,4,200,4)
) As Rnd
ORDER BY RandomString
```

This might seem like a waist since you're generating twice as many random strings as you need, However:

1. I'm not sure that's actually the case. The query optimizer might just stop execution once you have 100 distinct values.
2. Performance tests I've done for this function (on a relatively strong SQL Server 2016) shows it is lightning-fast, at least with a small number of strings:

   - Generating 200 strings average around 23 milliseconds.
   - Generating 2000 strings average around 55 milliseconds.
   - Generating 100,000 strings average around 2.8 seconds.

Generating 1 million strings, however, average around 30 seconds.

Comment: I have one more pattern `(\d){1-5}.(\d){2}` and which should give `123.76`, `45.69`, `9563.50`. Can you please help me with this case.

Comment: In this case, perhaps it's better to just revert to the [new and improved random string generator function](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/10/a-more-controllable-random-string-generator-function-for-sql-server/) and handle the non-random part of the string outside the function. That would make a slightly more cumbersome code but it will give you a much more flexible solution.